# Unexpected end of input moodle

Tags: php, json, moodle

I have a Moodle 2.9.1 that was migrated from another server

I have a problem when I load in a specific category moodle, in the other categories it's working fine

The code error is Unexpected end of input

File in Chrome inspector:
/course/category.ajax.php Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I've enabled debugger mode and got this:

Stack trace:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input    at Object.parse (native)    at Object.Y.namespace.parse (/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple.js&rollup/1452167486/mcore-debug.js:24483:18)    at Object.NS.process_results
(/theme/yui_combo.php?m/1452167486/course/categoryexpander/categoryexpander-debug.js:398:23)    at Y.Subscriber._notify
(/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple.js&rollup/1452167486/mcore-debug.js:13680:35)    at Y.Subscriber.notify
(/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple.js&rollup/1452167486/mcore-debug.js:13709:24)    at Y.CustomEvent._notify
(/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple.js&rollup/1452167486/mcore-debug.js:13372:17)    at Y.CustomEvent._procSubs
(/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple.js&rollup/1452167486/mcore-debug.js:13498:36)    at Y.CustomEvent.fireSimple
(/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple.js&rollup/1452167486/mcore-debug.js:13465:18)    at Y.CustomEvent._fire
(/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple.js&rollup/1452167486/mcore-debug.js:13447:29)    at Object.ET.fire
(/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple.js&rollup/1452167486/mcore-debug.js:14600:22)
```

I'll keep Googling

Regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok all my problems were the memory, I had few memory on my server